# Element appears in the same line

Tags: css

I have to make in html a calendar. I want to make this with tables.

All I want is the "2" to be in the same line with the others elements(3,4,5...etc).

Code:

```
<table class="calendar-program col-md-12">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>L</th>
         <th>M</th>
         <th>M</th>
         <th>J</th>
         <th>V</th>
         <th>S</th>
          <th>D</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
         <td>2
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <small class="event-calendar">1 event</small>
        </td>
          <td>3</td>
           <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
             <td>6</td>
             <td>7</td>


      </tr>


     </tbody>

   </table>
```

CSS:

```
table.calendar-program >tbody> tr>td{
    width: 14%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;        
}

small.event-calendar{
    clear: both;
    color: #000!important;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44aXS/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `vertical-align: top;` to the CSS for your `td`.

That will give you a layout like this:

[image: calendar with numbers at the top of the boxes]

Comment: So easy...Thanks Matthew!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a nicer, more controlled result with positioning, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B32Cc/

```
table.calendar-program >tbody> tr>td{
    width: 14%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
small.event-calendar{
    clear: both;
    color: #000!important;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```